# Getting errors when tring to install Angular/cli

Tags: angular, installation

I'm tring to install Angular with npm i -g @angular/cli
and get this error:
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://skimdb.npmjs.com/registry/@angular%2fcli reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-04-16T16_53_57_639Z-debug-0.log

maybe it has something to do with the fact that i don't have the folder npm-cache in my AppData/Roaming/
(I do have npm there)

Comment: The error you're seeing suggests that there was an issue with fetching the JSON response from the npm registry. One possible cause for this error is a problem with your internet connection or network.

You could try running the command again after checking your network connection. If the problem persists, you could try clearing your npm cache by running `npm cache clean --force` and then try running the command again.

If the issue still persists, you could try updating npm by running `npm install -g npm` and then try installing Angular again.

Comment: I get the same error before when running the command npm install -g npm